# Simple NSLayoutContraint usage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm looking for a simple Swift solution for a child view to programmatically fill a super view using NSLayoutContraint. It should be easy to understand. I feel like most of the answers on here currently are more complex than needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining [Rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) suggestion and my NSLayoutConstraint extension concept, I've settled on this in order to have a 1 line simple "fill superview" command:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    public static func activateConstraintsEqualToSuperview(child: NSView) {

        if ( child.superview == nil ) {
            Swift.print("NSLayoutConstraint.fillSuperview() superview of child is nil")
            return;
        }

        child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints( [
            child.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( child.superview!.leadingAnchor ),
            child.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( child.superview!.trailingAnchor ),
            child.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( child.superview!.topAnchor ),
            child.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( child.superview!.bottomAnchor )
            ])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraintsEqualToSuperview(child)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    public static func simpleConstraints( view:NSView, direction:NSString = "H", padding1:Int = 0, padding2:Int = 0 ) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("\(direction):|-\(padding1)-[view]-\(padding2)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":view])
        return constraint
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
parent.addConstraints( NSLayoutConstraint.simpleConstraints(child, direction: "H") )
parent.addConstraints( NSLayoutConstraint.simpleConstraints(child, direction: "V") )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've already set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` and added `subview` as a subview of `view`, you can set the four constraints, like so:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    subview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor),
    subview.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor),
    subview.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor),
    subview.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Or in Swift 3:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution using visual format:

```
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = ["subview":subview]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[subview]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[subview]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

And an even simpler solution, not using auto layout at all:

```
    subview.frame = view.bounds
    subview.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```